# Error passing a pillar variable with special characters to Salt's cmd.script

Tags: powershell, salt-stack

I'm doing some automation with Salt using cmd.script with Powershell as the shell. While passing arguments to the state module, I get the error **" Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Conn_String'. Cannot convert value to type System.String."**
I saw this error can be resolved in a regular powershell script by wrapping the variable passed as an argument in single quotes('') but I don't know how I can achieve the same behavior in a salt state file where the variable is set using jinja as seen below. If I enclose Conn_String in single quotes like this  `"-Conn_String" + 'Conn_String'` in the args, i get Conn_String in the PowerShell when I Write-Host instead of the actual connection string. I appreciate any help in resolving this.

Here is an example of my state and PowerShell script:

```
# pillar info in state
# content of Conn_String is "Server=testServer,2022;database=exampleDatabase;Integrated Security=SSP"

{% set var1 = pillar['var1'] %}
{% set var2 = pillar['var2'] %}
{% set Conn_String = pillar['Conn_String'] %}
{% set args = " -var1 " + var1 + " -var2 " + var2 + " -Conn_String " + Conn_String %}

CallPowerShell:
  cmd.script: 
    - source: {{ salt:// + pillar['var1'] + "/scripts/sendmail.ps1" %}
    - shell: powershell
    -cwd: D:\
    - args: {{ args }} 



# The PowerShell script(sendmail.ps1) that is called
param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory)]
     [string]$var2
     
     [Parameter(Mandatory)]
     [string]$Conn_String
     )
     Write-Host "$Conn_String"
     ...
```

Comment: Any reason your type-constraining your variables to `string`? Just remove the cast and you should be good as it'll default to `[object]`.

Comment: It sounds like all you need is `... var2 + " -Conn_String '" + Conn_String + "'" ...` - this assumes that Conn_String itself doesn't contain `'` (in which case you'd have to escape such embedded `'` as `''`).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I have removed the type-constraints, I'm still getting an error. This time though, the Write-Host printed "Server=testServer,2022" and the error message now says: **" The term 'Server=testServer,2022' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function blah blah...."** I think because of the semicolon(;) in the string, it's seeing it as a command seperator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/----command-separator- .

Comment: @mklement0 I tried wrapping that in quotes, it's failing with failed jinja syntax error: expected token 'end of statement block'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each level, Jinja2 then YAML, you need to ensure you have a valid string with the single quotes inside:

```yaml
{% set args = " -var1 '" ~ var1 ~ "' -var2 '" ~ var2 ~ "' -Conn_String '" ~ Conn_String ~ "'" %}

Call PowerShell:
  cmd.script: 
    - source: "salt://{{ var1 }}/scripts/sendmail.ps1"
    - shell: powershell
    - cwd: D:\
    - args: {{ args|yaml_dquote }}
```

Or alternatively, without the intermediate variables:

```yaml
Call PowerShell:
  cmd.script: 
    - source: "salt://{{ pillar['var1'] }}/scripts/sendmail.ps1"
    - shell: powershell
    - cwd: D:\
    - args: "-var1 '{{ pillar['var1'] }}' -var2 '{{ pillar['var2'] }}' -Conn_String '{{ pillar['Conn_String'] }}'"
```

If some of the variables might also contain quotes, then you should add `|yaml_encode` filters to ensure they are `\`-escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting the string at the semicolon and joining it with an underscore since Powershell interprets the semicolon in the string as a command separator. This is a workaround - I'll still prefer an approach that transmits this string without any manipulation. Here is how I resolved it for now.

```
...
{% set Conn_String = pillar['Conn_String'].split(' ') | join('_') %} # this add _ to Integrated Security=SSPI
{% set Temp_Conn_String = Conn_String.split(';') | join('_') %} # handles the ; in "Server=testServer,2022;database=exampleDatabase;Integrated_Security=SSP"
{% set args = ... + var2 + " -Temp_Conn_String " + Temp_Conn_String %}



param(
     $var2,
     $Temp_Conn_String
     )
     # With this I'm able to retrieve the original connection string
     $Conn_String = $Temp_Conn_String -split " " -join "," -split "_",3 -join ";" -split "_" -join " "
     Write-Host "$Conn_String"
```